# Android "public String"

Tags: java, android

here is my code:

```
public void generujCislo(int pocetCislic)
{
    TextView generovaneCislo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.generujCislo);
    Random random = new Random();
    String nahodnaCislice;
    int jedenCyklus = 0;


    while(pocetCislic>jedenCyklus)
    {
        nahodnaCislice = String.valueOf(random.nextInt(10 - 0) + 0);
        nahodnaCisla = nahodnaCisla + nahodnaCislice;

        jedenCyklus++;
    }

    generovaneCislo.setText((nahodnaCisla));


    zadaniCisel();

}
```

How I can use **String nahodnaCisla** with generated value in other class and there setText to new TextView? Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an util class, with method that will provide needed value:

```
public final class Utils {
 private static String nahodnaCisla;
 public static String get(int pocetCislic) {
   Random random = new Random();
    String nahodnaCislice;
    int jedenCyklus = 0;


    while(pocetCislic>jedenCyklus)
    {
        nahodnaCislice = String.valueOf(random.nextInt(10 - 0) + 0);
        nahodnaCisla = nahodnaCisla + nahodnaCislice;

        jedenCyklus++;
    }

    return nahodnaCisla;
  } 
}
```

If you need the same value in every view, use a static variable to hold it in util class.

Use like this:

```
TextView generovaneCislo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.generujCislo);
generovaneCislo.setText(Utils.get(pocetCislic));
```

Change names of methods as needed.